# Quickly/Glade linking a button to notebook page

Tags: application-development, pygtk, glade

Hey everyone (boy I seem to be posting quite a bit), I have a question regarding Glade and Quickly. Is it possible to map a button to a notebook within the same program. Like say for instance I have a toolbar with a button on it. Can I link it to, say page 3, on the notebook widget?

For instance, I have a button on my toolbar. While I know how to map it to external programs, I am uncertain as to how I would map it to page 3 (an example in this case). I don't want to open another window (already can do that), but I do not know how to link it to something already in the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do. Use **gtk.Notebook.set_current_page**

For example:

```
def on_button1_clicked(self, widget):
    self.notebook1.set_current_page(2)
```

Comment: That was EXACTLY what I needed. Thanks man :D. I didn't know about the .set_current_page() part, so that's what was messing me up.